# every instance of sharepoint in folder extensions\14 layouts\images has same Pictures?

Tags: web-services

Has every instance of sharepoint in folder extensions\14  layouts\images the same Pictures?

I want to build an Application which takes over this reference the Icons:
For example:
http://sharepointSite/_layouts/images/icdoc.png

I don't have many Sharepoint Serverpages for testing....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every single site that references /_Layouts/images will see this folder identically, if that's what your asking. icdoc.png will be accessible no matter what site or web application you're in.

Comment: that's true James. I think he wants http://site1/_layouts/images/img1.png and http://site2/_layouts/images/img1.png to be different images which is not possible because _layouts is virtual folder mapped to a physical location on Sharepoint root folder. You can have a subfolder created under LAYOUTS folder and host different images though

Comment: And yes, it is not recommended to change images that are referred under _layouts/images folder..

Comment: Thx to James and Ashish that was fast.
I mean if you have more instances of share point...
Iam building an App which will solve the images for more than one sharepoint server instances.
 sharepointServer1/site1/_layouts/images/img1.png
 sharepointServer2/site1/_layouts/images/img1.png

Are the images the same on every Serverinstance?

Comment: I think it all boils down to which image exist at C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\IMAGES on each server. Typically, if the image was deployed by SharePoint and no one updated the images folder intentionally or accidentally, it should be same image on both server.

Comment: Big thx Ashish.
Thats what I needed to know.
That means that every Standard Sharepoint Image has the same Images physically which I can  get over  site/_layouts/images/img...
Thats exactly what I needed

Answer (score 1):

Any url that contains "/_layouts/" actually points to the /14/TEMPLATE/LAYOUTS/ folder in the 14 hive on physical the SharePoint server.  There aren't multiple instances of it, there is only one regardless of the URL used to reference it.

If you need different images per site collection then you should put them in /Style Library/ instead.

EDIT - if you need to change that particular image to point to something else, you might need to modify your /14/TEMPLATE/XML/docicon.xml file and change the references to your new icon.